# If the left operand to the ?? operator is not null, does the right operand get evaluated?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I'm looking at using the `??` operator (null-coalescing operator) in C#. But the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) at MSDN is limited.

**My question:** If the left-hand operand is not null, does the right-hand operand ever get evaluated?

Comment: Try it yourself: `string s = "A"; Console.WriteLine("Hello" ?? a.Substring(10));`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As ever, the C# specification is the best place to go for this sort of thing.

From section 7.13 of the [C# 5 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (emphasis mine):

> A null coalescing expression of the form `a ?? b` requires `a` to be of a nullable type or reference type. If `a` is non-null, the result of `a ?? b` is `a`; otherwise, the result is `b`. **The operation evaluates `b` only if `a` is null.**

There are more details around when any conversions are performed, and the exact behaviour, but that's the main point given your question. It's also worth noting that the null-coalescing operator is right-associative, so `a ?? b ?? c` is evaluated as `a ?? (b ?? c)`... which means it will only evaluate `c` if *both* `a` and `b` are null.

Comment: Thanks never thought to check the Spec

Comment: @AntarrByrd: *Always* check the spec :) The C# spec is one of the best-written I've seen, and it's the authoritative source for this sort of thing.

Comment: Does this operator's associativity actually have any observable effect on its behavior? I'm trying to think of a case where `(a ?? b) ?? c` would behave differently from `a ?? (b ?? c)`, and I can't think of one.

Comment: @JLRishe: It has an effect if `a`, `b` and `c` have different types, and the language ends up performing conversions from one type to another. I had an example at some point, but I don't have it readily available.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Why not test it :)

```
void Main()
{
    var leftOrRight = left ?? right;
}

public bool? left 
{
    get
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Left hit");
        return true;
    }
}

public bool right 
{
    get
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Right hit");
        return true;
    }   
}
```

And the answer to the question is `no`... The second value doesn't get evaluated

Answer (score 4):

From the specification:

> A null coalescing expression of the form a ?? b requires a to be of a nullable type or reference type. If a is non-null, the result of a ?? b is a; otherwise, the result is b. ***The operation evaluates b only if a is null.***

(Emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. If name is not null, console show "MyName". If it's null, console shows "Called" then "Allo"

```
using System;           
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string name = "MyName";

        Console.WriteLine(name??test());
    }

    private static string test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        return "Allo";
    }
}
```