# Can I get the default value for a null value removal expression in C#?

Tags: c#, expression

Given the `dynamic` `object`, if there is a way to get the default value in an expression of `null` value removal? code snippet may look like as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dynamico : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>, ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged, IXmlSerializable
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return GetProperty(key); }
        set
        {
            _values[key] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(key);
        }
    }

    public object GetProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(propertyName) == true)
        {
            return _values[propertyName];
        }
        return RequestProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = GetProperty(binder.Name);
        **//To do: to get the default value of null value removal expression**
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        return base.TryInvoke(binder, args, out result);
    }
    ......
}
```

I may use below code to utilize the `class`:

```
dynamic obj = new Dynamico();
.......
var t = obj.DemoProp ?? "Default value is assigned";
```

My question is in the `TryGetMember` method of the `Dynamic` `class` definition, how to get the default value, ie. "Default value is assigned"? The solution may use Expressions, can any buddy suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks every body, Why I need to achieve this is because I am developing a multi-template supported CMS engine powered by MVC which I would like to keep the template friendly to the developers, etc.... (forgive me skip the long story...)

here I have come up a solution, just paste the code below which haven't optimized yet.

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
var frames = st.GetFrames();
System.Diagnostics.StackFrame expfm = null;
for (int i = 0; i < frames.Length; i++)
{
    string fn = frames[i].GetMethod().Name;
    if (fn == "get_Item" || fn == "UpdateAndExecute1") // to find the caller
    {
        expfm = frames[i + 1];
        break;
    }
    else if (fn == "Execute")
    {
        expfm = frames[i];
        break;
    }
}
if (expfm != null)
{
    var mb = expfm.GetMethod().GetMethodBody();
    byte[] il = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
    int offset = expfm.GetILOffset();
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = offset; i < il.Length && i <= offset + 100; i++)
    {
        if (il[i] == OpCodes.Brtrue_S.Value && il[i + 2] == OpCodes.Pop.Value && il[i + 3] == OpCodes.Ldstr.Value)
        {
            offset = i + 4;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        int mt = ReadInt32(il, ref offset);
        var defs = expfm.GetMethod().Module.ResolveString(mt);
    }
}

    private static int ReadInt32(byte[] il, ref int position)
    {
        return (((il[position++] | (il[position++] << 8)) | (il[position++] << 0x10)) | (il[position++] << 0x18));
    }
```

The variable 'defs', contains the default value which I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `TryConvert`:

```
public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
{

    if (binder.Type == typeof(String))
    {
        result = node.Value;

        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

More reading here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject/

Comment: thanks Gauravsa. Just looked at and tried. It seems TryCovert will be called when type conversion is executing, like: object o = (Dynamico)obj; not a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, at least not with the syntax you're using now. In the expression `obj.DemoProp ?? "Default value is assigned"`, it is the evaluation of the left-hand operand that implicitly invokes `Dynamico.TryGetMember`, and as discussed in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024328/if-the-left-operand-to-the-operator-is-not-null-does-the-right-operand-get-e), C# does not even evaluate the right-hand operand of the null-coalescing operator (`??`) unless and until it determines that the left-hand operand is null. Therefore the value of `"Default value is assigned"`—or whatever expression you put in its place—cannot be available to a method invoked by the evaluation of `obj.DemoProp`, because its value hasn't even been determined yet.

If you want the same piece of logic that determines the value of a property that may or may not exist on your dynamic class to also have access to the default value, then you'll have to provide a method specifically for that purpose, and rely on users of your class to invoke that method instead of using the null-coalescing operator. For instance, instead of `obj.DemoProp ?? "Default value is assigned"`, you might write `obj.GetValueOrDefault("DemoProp", "Default value is assigned")` and then add a `GetValueOrDefault` method to `Dynamico` that does whatever it is you're trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Joe. If it's truth, then would be so sad. Whereas I am still wondering if there is a way to get the expression (ie. System.Linq.Expression) of which to call the obj.DemoProp, if there is, then I just need to execute that expression. Or by System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class, I can get the method which call obj.DemoProp, but it looks like a too big code block to do this... stuck....

Comment: I don't think it's sad; it's a deliberate and sensible design decision on the part of the authors of C#. Even if you could do what you want to do, I think it would be a bad idea. C# programmers are accustomed to writing expressions like `a ?? b` or `a && b` with the expectation that `b` will never be evaluated if the value of `a` makes it unnecessary to do so. What you want would invalidate that expectation.